# Passing url in web view as i scroll down it Stuck

Tags: android, webview, popupwindow

[image][image: View at the bottom of my activity is hide popupwindow]   This is my Java Code I'm Inflating another layout on this same activity and using popupview to show:

```
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) StudyMaterial.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View popupview = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.webview, null);
            PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupview, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
            WebView web = (WebView) popupview.findViewById(R.id.main);
            ImageView cancel = (ImageView) popupview.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            web.getScrollY();
            cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                }
            });
            web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            //web.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
            web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
            //Toast.makeText(TeacherHome.this,"https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+url,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            web.loadUrl("http://www.javatpoint.com");
            popupWindow.showAsDropDown(popupview, 0, 0, Gravity.CENTER);
```

And this is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:elevation="3dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:title="View">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/cancel1"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/cancel"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
<WebView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

As i scroll down my activity get stuck and start blinking after that its toolbar show at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your layout like this and try again:

```
<WebView
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dialog instead of popup window. which is more customizable and implementation is very easy..

```
 final Dialog d=new Dialog(this,R.style.fullscreendialog);
        d.setContentView(R.layout.webview);
        WebView web = (WebView) d.findViewById(R.id.main);
        ImageView cancel = (ImageView) d.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                d.dismiss();
            }
        });
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //web.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        //Toast.makeText(TeacherHome.this,"https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+url,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        web.loadUrl("http://www.javatpoint.com";
        d.show();
        d.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

add this to your style

```
<style name=fullscreendialog/>
```

Reason behind adding theme dialog inherit as parent of Theme.dialog which makes it shrink just removing parent from theme works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek it works and also add this line to open all windows on webview not in browser.     web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());